# What's wrong with my Query?

Tags: android

I know I have asked this question already, but hopefully a fresh set of eyes will look at it.  I have written this method below to return one specific value as a test for my Query.  However every time i run the program it crashes when it reaches the line beginning Cursor. Here is the code:

```
public String getData(){
    String rName= "";
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TELEPHONE, COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_MENUURL, COLUMN_WEBSITE, COLUMN_MOBILE};
    SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);
    Cursor item = rDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, "name like 'Terry'", null, null, null, null);
    rDb.close();
    for(item.moveToFirst();item.moveToNext(); item.isAfterLast()) {
        rName = item.getString(item.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
    }


    return rName;

}
```

Anything wrong with what i have written? rDb is the name of the database.

Comment: should probably be something like `rDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);` since this is what returns an opened database.

Comment: thank you very much that made the query work!! although now there is an issue with the loop.  have i got the movetonext and isafterlast the wrong way round?

Comment: you are closing db to quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);
```

to

```
rDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, 0);
```

`SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase` returns an open database. Your `rDb` is not set otherwise (though we cannot see the full code, so I cannot be certain).